# jQuery Refresh Captcha is Reloading Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why the `#reload` click event is reloading whole page instead of refreshing the `#cap-img` source?

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="input-group-addon-captcha"><img id="cap-img" src="captcha.php"></span>
      <input id="seo-captcha" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Text" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon seo-addon-right"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-q" id="reload"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button></span>
   </div>
</div>

  <script>
  $(function() {            
    $('#reload').click(function(){  
     $('#cap-img').attr('src', 'captcha.php?' + (new Date).getTime());
    });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that button is part of a form, which your form is capturing as a submit handler by default. Try this:

```
$('#reload').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cap-img').attr('src', 'captcha.php?' + (new Date).getTime());
});
```

Plunker of this example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/y62jdX6sGsU8IQFJPmDz?p=preview